# Bulk update pages that use old URL alias by content type

Tags: 8, hooks, path-aliases

We have a content type, `Basic Page` that recently had the URL pattern changed from `www.example.com/page/page-title` to `www.example.com/page-title`. Under the [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) settings found at `/admin/config/search/path/update_bulk` there are options to `Select the types of paths for which to generate URL aliases` which allows for selecting different entities such as `Content`. Additionally there is `Select which URL aliases to generate` where we want `Update the URL alias for paths having an old URL alias` as the choice.

[image: bulk generate path alias]

We don't want to update all `Content` entities, but rather we want to update by `content type`.

**How would we update `URL alias` after changing the `path pattern` by `content type` either programmatically or through an existing module?**

The goal is to be able to do update all `Basic Pages` URL alias, but not others.

Comment: You’ll have to dive into the code, the module simply doesn’t have that feature

Comment: I think you can just create a new pattern for the basic page content type? If I understand the question correctly.

Comment: @cchen The question is regarding what is needed to update `basic pages` that are using the old URL pattern after creating the new pattern.

Answer (score 4):

you can disable patterns that you dont want to update. In this way update will only update the patterns belong to content types

Comment: @Onur Are you saying to navigate to `/admin/config/search/path/patterns` page and then set them to be disabled?